# How to add string resources and toggle language for new Azure API management development portal

Tags: string, azure-api-management

I am using Azure's APIM development portal (the latest one, not legacy) and am wondering how I can add string resources to toggle between English and French language. Also, how can I access and edit the JavaScript code that is rendering the static page?

Answer (score 0):

This feature not yet implemented, but it is planned. Please check back in a few weeks.